# PHP Regex not working

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace all $[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f] in my text but using the following Regular Expression (PHP) its not working.

I have the text

```
$000T$111e$222s$333t
```

but with my regex

```
preg_replace("\$[0-9a-fA-F]{3}", "", $text);
```

its not working.

Expected:

```
Test
```

Return value: Empty String

I tried the RegEx on websites like DebuggEx and my expression worked perfectly well.

What could cause the issue?

Comment: You're missing perl-style delimiters: `/\$[0-9a-fA-F]{3}/`

Comment: @MikeB then my given text is unchanged

Comment: Found the issue: just the code `/\$[0-9a-fA-F]{3}/`
was a great first attempt. Just needed to escape the \ like: `/\\$[0-9a-fA-F]{3}/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape \ if you using double quotes:

```
preg_replace("/\\$[0-9a-fA-F]{3}/", "", $text);
```

or easier use single quotes:

```
preg_replace('/\$[0-9a-fA-F]{3}/', '', $text);
```